# NumberFormatException when create Short number

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception, short

I am working on wrapper classes during facing the NumberFormatException in the following code please tell me why do we not face compile time error before this Runtime exception, Why there is no compile time error only just runtime NumberFormat Exception.

```
Short s3 = new Short("32770");
System.out.println(s3);
```

Exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"32770" Radix:10

Comment: Evaluation is done in runtime, not in compile time

Answer (score 2):

See the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

`Short`ranges from `-32,768`  to `32,767` in java. `32770` is not a valid `short`.

Comment: @iramkahkashan Don't thank for response, upvote and accept answers instead.

Answer (score 0):

You will get exception only in following cases:

```
An exception of type NumberFormatException is thrown if any of the following situations occurs:

    The first argument is null or is a string of length zero.
    The radix is either smaller than Character.MIN_RADIX or larger than Character.MAX_RADIX.
    Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix, except that the first character may be a minus sign '-' ('\u002D') or plus sign '+' ('\u002B') provided that the string is longer than length 1.
    The value represented by the string is not a value of type short.
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before **Short** range is **from -32768 to 32767**. You are passing **"32770"** as a value to the **Short** constructor which is out of range.

You doesn't receive any compile time error, because you are passing a argument of the valid type to the constructor. 
The value is validated during actual execution which occurs in the runtime hence NumberFormatException and not any of the compile errors